# implement bandpass filter on complex valued signal? (C++)

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, bandpass, c++

I want to filter out complex valued samples - Bandpass filter.
I have 100 complex samples and I wish to filter out a range of frequencies from it, as you can see in the result of the FFT, there are 3 frequencies here.

1. First At 252KHz
2. Second At 315KHz
3. Third At 378KHz

[image]
I want to only keep the middle one (315KHz)

I am using this [simple FIR filter class by by Mike Perkins](https://github.com/mihaibujanca/soundGR/tree/master/FIR-filter-class) class, it already includes 3 filters, LPF, HPF and BPF which is what I need.

The problem is, it was designed to work with real samples, i.e wav files, now I am trying to get around this but I'm having troubles doing so, you can find documentation of his class in the github link, but I'm going to post the filter class here below,.

I'm going to focus on the `do_sample(float data_sample)` function, this function takes a real data sample as input, and it returns real filtered data sample.

Here is the code for it:

```
float Filter::do_sample(float data_sample)
{
    int i;
    float result;

    if( m_error_flag != 0 ) return(0);

    for(i = m_num_taps - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        m_sr[i] = m_sr[i-1];
    }   
    m_sr[0] = data_sample;

    result = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m_num_taps; i++) result += m_sr[i] * m_taps[i];

    return result;
}
```

What I've tried to do:

1. I tried sending the real and imaginary parts separately to the function
2. I tried making 2 separate `Filter` objects, one for the real part and the other for the imaginary parts and using the function with each object

both "solutions" didn't work and returning me the same result:

[image]

Finally, here is the filter class:

filt.h

```
#ifndef _FILTER_H
#define _FILTER_H

#define MAX_NUM_FILTER_TAPS 1000
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>

enum filterType {LPF, HPF, BPF};

class Filter{
    private:
        filterType m_filt_t;
        int m_num_taps;
        int m_error_flag;
        float m_Fs;
        float m_Fx;
        float m_lambda;
        float *m_taps;
        float *m_sr;
        void designLPF();
        void designHPF();

        // Only needed for the bandpass filter case
        float m_Fu, m_phi;
        void designBPF();

    public:
        Filter(filterType filt_t, int num_taps, float Fs, float Fx);
        Filter(filterType filt_t, int num_taps, float Fs, float Fl, float Fu);
        ~Filter();
        void init();
        float do_sample(float data_sample);
        int get_error_flag(){return m_error_flag;};
        void get_taps( float *taps );
};

#endif
```

filt.cpp:

```
#include "filt.h"

#define ECODE(x) {m_error_flag = x; return;}

// Handles LPF and HPF case
Filter::Filter(filterType filt_t, int num_taps, float Fs, float Fx)
{
    m_error_flag = 0;
    m_filt_t = filt_t;
    m_num_taps = num_taps;
    m_Fs = Fs;
    m_Fx = Fx;
    m_lambda = M_PI * Fx / (Fs/2);

    if( Fs <= 0 ) ECODE(-1);
    if( Fx <= 0 || Fx >= Fs/2 ) ECODE(-2);
    if( m_num_taps <= 0 || m_num_taps > MAX_NUM_FILTER_TAPS ) ECODE(-3);

    m_taps = m_sr = NULL;
    m_taps = (float*)malloc( m_num_taps * sizeof(float) );
    m_sr = (float*)malloc( m_num_taps * sizeof(float) );
    if( m_taps == NULL || m_sr == NULL ) ECODE(-4);
    
    init();

    if( m_filt_t == LPF ) designLPF();
    else if( m_filt_t == HPF ) designHPF();
    else ECODE(-5);

    return;
}

// Handles BPF case
Filter::Filter(filterType filt_t, int num_taps, float Fs, float Fl,
               float Fu)
{
    m_error_flag = 0;
    m_filt_t = filt_t;
    m_num_taps = num_taps;
    m_Fs = Fs;
    m_Fx = Fl;
    m_Fu = Fu;
    m_lambda = M_PI * Fl / (Fs/2);
    m_phi = M_PI * Fu / (Fs/2);

    if( Fs <= 0 ) ECODE(-10);
    if( Fl >= Fu ) ECODE(-11);
    if( Fl <= 0 || Fl >= Fs/2 ) ECODE(-12);
    if( Fu <= 0 || Fu >= Fs/2 ) ECODE(-13);
    if( m_num_taps <= 0 || m_num_taps > MAX_NUM_FILTER_TAPS ) ECODE(-14);

    m_taps = m_sr = NULL;
    m_taps = (float*)malloc( m_num_taps * sizeof(float) );
    m_sr = (float*)malloc( m_num_taps * sizeof(float) );
    if( m_taps == NULL || m_sr == NULL ) ECODE(-15);
    
    init();

    if( m_filt_t == BPF ) designBPF();
    else ECODE(-16);

    return;
}

Filter::~Filter()
{
    if( m_taps != NULL ) free( m_taps );
    if( m_sr != NULL ) free( m_sr );
}

void 
Filter::designLPF()
{
    int n;
    float mm;

    for(n = 0; n < m_num_taps; n++){
        mm = n - (m_num_taps - 1.0) / 2.0;
        if( mm == 0.0 ) m_taps[n] = m_lambda / M_PI;
        else m_taps[n] = sin( mm * m_lambda ) / (mm * M_PI);
    }

    return;
}

void 
Filter::designHPF()
{
    int n;
    float mm;

    for(n = 0; n < m_num_taps; n++){
        mm = n - (m_num_taps - 1.0) / 2.0;
        if( mm == 0.0 ) m_taps[n] = 1.0 - m_lambda / M_PI;
        else m_taps[n] = -sin( mm * m_lambda ) / (mm * M_PI);
    }

    return;
}

void 
Filter::designBPF()
{
    int n;
    float mm;

    for(n = 0; n < m_num_taps; n++){
        mm = n - (m_num_taps - 1.0) / 2.0;
        if( mm == 0.0 ) m_taps[n] = (m_phi - m_lambda) / M_PI;
        else m_taps[n] = (   sin( mm * m_phi ) -
                             sin( mm * m_lambda )   ) / (mm * M_PI);
    }

    return;
}

void 
Filter::get_taps(float* taps)
{
    int i;

    if (m_error_flag != 0) return;

    for (i = 0; i < m_num_taps; i++) taps[i] = m_taps[i];

    return;
}

void 
Filter::init()
{
    int i;

    if( m_error_flag != 0 ) return;

    for(i = 0; i < m_num_taps; i++) m_sr[i] = 0;

    return;
}

float 
Filter::do_sample(float data_sample)
{
    int i;
    float result;

    if( m_error_flag != 0 ) return(0);

    for(i = m_num_taps - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        m_sr[i] = m_sr[i-1];
    }   
    m_sr[0] = data_sample;

    result = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m_num_taps; i++) result += m_sr[i] * m_taps[i];

    return result;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I added a main and recreated this issue so you can run it for yourself.

main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "filt.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using std::vector;
using std::complex;

typedef vector<complex<double>> complexSignal;

vector<double> doFilter(Filter* my_filter, const complexSignal& samples, int N, bool real_part)
{
    vector<double> to_return;
    float part;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (real_part)
            part = my_filter->do_sample(samples[i].real());
        else
            part = my_filter->do_sample(samples[i].imag());
        to_return.push_back(part);
    }
    return to_return;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    complexSignal complex_samples;
    int frequency1 = 252000;
    int frequency2 = 315000;
    int frequency3 = 378000;

    double Fs = 1260000.0;
    const double  T = 1 / Fs;

    //generate complex sine wave
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        complex_samples.push_back({ (0.7 * cos(2 * M_PI * frequency1 * (i * T))), (0.7 * sin(2 * M_PI * frequency1 * (i * T))) });
        complex_samples[i] += { (0.7 * cos(2 * M_PI * frequency2 * (i * T))), (0.7 * sin(2 * M_PI * frequency2 * (i * T))) };
        complex_samples[i] += { (0.7 * cos(2 * M_PI * frequency3 * (i * T))), (0.7 * sin(2 * M_PI * frequency3 * (i * T))) };
    }

    Filter* BPF_Filter_real;
    Filter* BPF_Filter_imag;

    BPF_Filter_real = new Filter(BPF, 51, 1260.0, 308.7, 321.3);
    BPF_Filter_imag = new Filter(BPF, 51, 1260.0, 308.7, 321.3);

    vector<double> real_filtered = doFilter(BPF_Filter_real, complex_samples, 100, 1);
    vector<double> imag_filtered = doFilter(BPF_Filter_imag, complex_samples, 100, 0);

    complexSignal complex_filtered;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        complex_filtered.push_back({ real_filtered[i], imag_filtered[i] });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2: RESULTS:**
[image]

Comment: Filtering is linear, so $\textrm{BPF}\lbrace a(t)+jb(t) \rbrace = \textrm{BPF}\lbrace a(t) \rbrace + j \textrm{BPF}\lbrace b(t) \rbrace$.

Comment: So you're saying I should filter the real and imag part separately, but I already tried that (look in the post) @MBaz

Comment: Yeah -- but if you know it _should_ work, the conclusion is that the problem is in your code, not in your approach.

Comment: I understand, so I created a small main file with how I implemented this and added it to the post, kindly take a look at let me know if you spot anything wrong, you can also run it for yourself. @MBaz

Comment: @yarinCohen you're simply not doing BPF(real) and BPF(imag); you're doing the identical call for both `BPF_Filter_real` and `_imag`.  This is really just a debugging, not a signal processing problem, and using your debugger would have led you to the same conclusion as I just did about you calling `doFilter` with exactly the same arguments.

Comment: Regarding your code: This is far from a minimal example, you're including C headers that you really should not be including in a C++ program , you're including C++ headers you don't use, and you're disabling warnings for your own header, which is almost certainly a sign of you needing to fix your header!!! Also, you forget to enable them afterwards. So: it's a problem of C++ coding, not of signal processing; that's a good thing, honestly, because using compiler warnings and a debugger can help you fix them quickly.

Comment: "you're doing the identical call for both" well yeah that was how I thought it should be, like it's not really identical because the real and imag part are not mixed like if I used one `Filter` object

Regarding the headers, I simply forgot to remove those from testing other stuff, I just removed them now and the problem still proceeds @MarcusMüller

Comment: (more free code review: you're passing `std::vector`s by value – which means you're copying them. That's almost certainly not what you want! You should use `const complex_signal &` as argument type instead.)

Comment: @yarinCohen there's enough other C++ problems in here, sorry, again, this is a debugging not a signal processing problem. For example, don't forget your filter has state – you can't just use it for both.

Comment: I always like taking notes to make my code better, but what is the problem with coping `samples` by value?  @MarcusMüller

Comment: it literally means that when calling `doFilter`, memory is allocated at a new location, and your input vectors are copied to that memory, just to be then thrown away / dealocated at the end of `doSamples`. That is relatively expensive.

Comment: Well yeah but it's not really a C++ problem that caused the main issue I was talking about however I did fix that and updated the post, do you spot anything else? @MarcusMüller

Comment: Again, I've already told you that you can't just re-use the same `Filter`, as it has state. This **is** a C++ coding, not a signal processing problem, and *debugging* is the way forward!

Comment: Yeah you we're right, after debugging I found a few issues and it now works, however the results are not as "smooth" as I expected it to be (added results to the post), is this normal after filtering? also I know I can use windowing such as Hann window to make it smoother. @MarcusMüller